# How to keep a Zip file from becoming corrupted when streamed

Tags: php, download, zip

I'm having an issue with streaming a Zip file for download with PHP.  Here is my code:

```
$arrFiles = $this->getRequest()->getPost('files', array());
$objFacultyClubDownloads = new FacultyClub_Downloads();
$objFCDownloads = $objFacultyClubDownloads->saveFacultyClubDownloadsInfo($arrFiles);

// create the zip file

 $strZipName = 'download' . time() . '.zip';
 $strZipSavePath = PUBLIC_PATH . '/downloads/temp/';

 $objZip = new ZipArchive;

 if ($objZip->open($strZipSavePath . $strZipName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

 foreach ($arrFiles['file_name'] as $intKey => $strValue) {
     $strFilePath = PUBLIC_PATH . $strValue;
     if (file_exists($strFilePath)) {
         $strFileName = strtolower(basename($strValue));
         $objZip->addFile($strFilePath, $strFileName);
      }
  }

   $strZipName = $objZip->filename;
   $objZip->close();
}
// strip out the layout and view

$this->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();

 // stream the zip file

 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Faculty-Club-Download.zip");
 //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($strZipName));
 readfile($strZipName);
```

This is in Zend Framework.  The issue seems to be the streaming.  The download is properly created in the temp folder.  I can unzip that Zip just fine.  But when the file is streamed for download, it unzips a file with the extension .cpgz.  From what I am reading, this means the Zip is corrupt.  When I double click it to unzip it, I just get another verison of the same file with the .cpgz extension -- it duplicates itself.

I've tried adding `ob_clean` and `flush` before `readfile`, but that didn't help.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

If the file on the server is valid, but upon transferring over http becomes corrupt, I would look at everything between PHP and the browser.  Assuming you're using Apache, start there and disable gzip for this request.  We have run into similar issues with reverse proxies and double compression.

Probably have to call this pretty early in your PHP code:

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
```

http://php.net/apache_setenv

Comment: It probably is an environment issue.  The code works on the live server, but not in my test environment.  So something is configured differently on the live server.  Thanks, @machee.